# Dynamic div from bottom of page - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert a new div each time a new user is found in my database. I have the following code working if I change the CSS (remove "bottom" and "absolute" from the classes). The problem is that it starts at the top and each div is inserted below the previous one. I would like for the divs to be in the bottom left hand corner of the screen, and then move up when a new div is inserted. It would essentially push the existing divs up and the newest div would be at the bottom of the stack. Any ideas on how to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

This code will insert a new div, but it just places it on top of the previous one.

```
.greyBox {
    padding:8px;
    background: grey;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}
.redBox {
    padding:8px;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
    bottom:1;
    position:absolute;
}

<p>
  <button id="after">New User</button>
  <button id="reset">reset</button>
</p>

<div class="greyBox">Users</div>

$("#after").click(function () {
     $('.greyBox').after("<div class='redBox'>User 1</div>");
});

$("#reset").click(function () {
     location.reload();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ymTtB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new div container with class "bottom"
http://jsfiddle.net/4np4q/

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .bottom{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;     
    }
    .greyBox{
        padding:8px;
        background: grey;
        margin-bottom:8px;
        width:200px;
        height:50px;

    }

    .redBox{
        padding:8px;
        background: red;
        margin-bottom:8px;
        width:200px;
        height:25px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

  <p>
  <button id="after">New User</button>
  <button id="reset">reset</button>
  </p>

  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="greyBox">Users</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#after").click(function () {
      $('.greyBox').after("<div class='redBox'>User 1</div>");
    });

    $("#reset").click(function () {
      location.reload();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was using this as an example and I'll need to eliminate the buttons since the divs will be created automatically. How can I change this to be able to pass parameters. I guess I would like to make it a separate function that can be called from the program instead of on click.

Answer (score 0):

It's your `position: absolute` on `.redbox`:

```
.greyBox {
    padding:8px;
    background: grey;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    width:200px;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}

.redBox {
    padding:8px;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
}
```

Also, I imagined you were trying to add to the `.greyBox` element, instead of *after* it.

```
$("#after").click(function () {
     $('.greyBox').append("<div class='redBox'>User 1</div>");
});

$("#reset").click(function () {
     $('.greyBox').children().remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bb6am/

If you really do want `.after()` `greyBox`, you'll need to use a wrapper and apply the "bottom" style to it:

```
.users {
    width:200px;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}
.greyBox {
    padding:8px;
    background: grey;
    margin-bottom:8px;
}

<p>
  <button id="after">New User</button>
  <button id="reset">reset</button>
</p>

$("#after").click(function () {
     $('.greyBox').after("<div class='redBox'>User 1</div>");
});

$("#reset").click(function () {
     $('.users').children().not('.greyBox').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bb6am/2/